# how to use LayoutInflater on a SimpleCursorAdapter list in android?

Tags: android, layout, simplecursoradapter

given an example SimpleCursorAdapter implementation code:

```
String[] projection = new String[] {Browser.BookmarkColumns._ID, 
                                 Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, 
                                 Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL};
    String[] displayFields = new String[] {Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, 
                                 Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL};
    int[] displayViews = new int[] { android.R.id.text1, 
                                 android.R.id.text2 };

    Cursor cur = managedQuery(android.provider.Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, 
                   projection, null, null, null);
    setListAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, cur, 
                   displayFields, displayViews));
```

How can I use my own xml layout to show those list using LayoutInflater?

or maybe I could say "to make my own simple_list_item_2.xml"....

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SimpleCursorAdapter` handles the layout inflation for you. You just need to create your layout in `res/layout/my_list_item.xml` and then change `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2` to `R.layout.my_list_item`.

You would also change `android.R.id.text1` to the id of the `TextView` you want to bind the `TITLE` column to in your layout, for example `R.id.title`. Likewise for the `URL` column.

You can start with a copy of [simple_list_item_2.xml](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_2.xml) and experiment with editing it for your needs, saving it to `res/layout/my_list_item.xml` or whatever layout name you want.